# Immediately show indicator for field validation before submit (side effect handling)

Tags: reactjs, validation, dynamic, react-hook-form

I have the requirement to put an asterisk to a field label whenever this field is required

This doesn't pose any problem if the field is unconditionally required ... but I often have fields coming from dynamic form generation, where the user/form creator can decide to make the field only required if a certain condition is met (eventually depending on other field values, i.e. the field is ONLY required if the other field has a certain value).

For the asterisk I put the condition in place in order to render it conditionally, but the condition is not responsively evaluated. I even tried to setup a useEffect depending on `getValues("address.street")` but this is not triggered.

So my question is: How can I determine a rendering condition depending on other fields responsively in react-hook-form?

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-frhdso?file=src%2FApp.tsx&terminal=dev)

```
import './App.css';
import { SubmitHandler, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

type Address = {
  street: string;
  city: string;
};

type Inputs = {
  email: string;
  address: Address;
};

function App() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
    getValues,
  } = useForm<Inputs>();

  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<Inputs> = (formdata) => console.log(formdata);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Street address changed!');
  }, [getValues('address.street')]);
  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>&nbsp;
        <span className="formerror">*</span>
        <br />
        <input {...register('email', { required: true })} id="email" />
        <br />
        {errors.email ? (
          <span className="formerror">Email is required</span>
        ) : (
          <span></span>
        )}
        <br />
        <label htmlFor="street">Street</label>
        <br />
        <input {...register('address.street')} id="street" />
        <br />
        {errors.address?.street ? (
          <span className="formerror">Error in street</span>
        ) : (
          <span></span>
        )}
        <br />
        <label htmlFor="city">City</label>&nbsp;
        {getValues('address.street') ? (
          <span className="formerror">*</span>  <!-- this should be rendered responsively -->
        ) : (
          <></>
        )}
        <br />
        <input
          {...register('address.city', {
            validate: (value) => {
              if (getValues('address.street')) {
                console.log('Field is required!');
                if (!value)
                  return 'City is required when street address is given';
                else return true;
              }
              console.log('Field is not required!');
              return true;
            },
          })}
          id="city"
        />
        <br />
        {errors.address?.city ? (
          <span className="formerror">{errors.address?.city.message}</span>
        ) : (
          <span></span>
        )}
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```